# JS Retain Initial Value Obtained from Div after Changes to Div from JS itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<script>
document.getElementsByName("region").forEach(function(node) {
   node.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);
});

function myFunction() {

    var currentPrice = document.getElementById('ms2_order_cost').innerHTML;

    if (document.getElementById("region").value == "Ohio" || document.getElementById("region").value == "ohio") {

       var currentPriceF = parseFloat(currentPrice);
       var newPrice = currentPriceF * 1.0725;

       document.getElementById("ms2_order_cost").innerHTML = newPrice;
    }
    else {

        document.getElementById("ms2_order_cost").innerHTML = newPrice;
    }  
    return false;
}
</script>
```

What I would like is that in the else statement, I get the original value of the div (not the one which is displaying after the If condition is trigerred).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the initial price from `ms2_order_cost` and store it in `currentPrice`, you're not actually manipulating this variable any further. As such, you can simply change your `else` statement to use `currentPrice` instead of `newPrice`:

```
else {
  document.getElementById("ms2_order_cost").innerHTML = currentPrice;
}
```

As can be seen in the following:

```js
document.getElementsByName("region").forEach(function(node) {
  node.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);
});

function myFunction() {
  var currentPrice = document.getElementById('ms2_order_cost').innerHTML;
  if (document.getElementById("region").value == "Ohio" || document.getElementById("region").value == "ohio") {
    var currentPriceF = parseFloat(currentPrice);
    var newPrice = currentPriceF * 1.0725;
    document.getElementById("ms2_order_cost").innerHTML = newPrice;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ms2_order_cost").innerHTML = currentPrice;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Assuming you want to get the value on **page load** rather than after your trigger, you need to assign the variable after the page loads, but before the function is triggered:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var initialPrice = document.getElementById('ms2_order_cost').innerHTML;
}
```

And then make use of this variable, as is seen in the following:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var initialPrice = document.getElementById('ms2_order_cost').innerHTML;
}

document.getElementsByName("region").forEach(function(node) {
  node.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);
});

function myFunction() {
  var currentPrice = document.getElementById('ms2_order_cost').innerHTML;
  if (document.getElementById("region").value == "Ohio" || document.getElementById("region").value == "ohio") {
    var currentPriceF = parseFloat(currentPrice);
    var newPrice = currentPriceF * 1.0725;
    document.getElementById("ms2_order_cost").innerHTML = newPrice;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ms2_order_cost").innerHTML = initialPrice;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Note that this will only work if the element is available on page load! If it is not, substitute `window.onload()` for whatever causes your element to be added to the DOM.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I have done as you said, but the value in ms2_order_cost stays the same after triggering. For example, initial value shows 60, on trigerring the if it shows 68 - when trigerring the else the price stays 68.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying. In that case, you'll need to create a new variable and assign `document.getElementById("ms2_order_cost").innerHTML` to in **on page load**, and then make use of this variable. I've updated my answer to cover that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now the following error is outputing when I put exactly as per your answer: Uncaught ReferenceError: initialPrice is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.myFunction ((index):427)

Comment: Yep; sounds like that element is not initially available on page load. As stated, you'll need to replace the `window.onload` function with the timing that adds your element to the page. As you don't specify exactly when that is, I'm afraid I can't give you the exact code you'll need to do that sorry. But that's what you need to do :)

Comment: It's actually on the page immediately that div (not being manipulated by other js). What can I use to replace the window.onload :) ?